# Singular value decomposition of matrix shifted by a constant

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

This may be trivial but I couldn't figure it out. If SVD of matrix $X$ is $X = U \Sigma V^*$. For a constant value $c$ what is the SVD of $X-c$ ? From experiments it looks like only the largest singular value is affected.

Comment: Are you subtracting a scalar from a matrix?

Comment: If you're subtracting $c$ from every element of $x$, then this is more properly stated as $X\mapsto X-c uv^\top$ where $u,v$ are column vectors of ones with appropriate length. As such, $X-c uv^\top$ constitutes a rank-one update of $X$. (Looking around online, it isn't clear if there's a simple procedure for how the SVD will change under this mapping.)

Answer (score 3):

This problem is addressed in [Shifted Randomized SVD algorithm](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.11772.pdf). An implementation is available [here](https://github.com/abasirat/Shifted-Randomized-SVD).